# Error in VS-Code: found no \citation commands

Tags: bibliographies, citing, biber, macos, vscode

I am writing my thesis and run it on LaTex on VS-Code on a macOS and all of sudden from today morning I keep receiving the following error:

---

I found no \citation commands.

I found no \bibdata command.

I found no \bibstyle command.

---

The pdf file is generated but non of my references is working and is not showing anymore in the pdf. And the list of references is also gone. I attached a screenshot of the references in the generated pdf file.

There are the commands I use for the bibliography:

`\usepackage[backend=biber, style=numeric, alldates=comp, sorting=none]{biblatex}`
`\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}`

Afterwards, I try it on windows pc and I ran it and it worked.

So, I have no idea what is going on and if there is anyone who can help me, I would appreciate any comment and any idea.
[image]

Comment: In the context of a `biblatex` bibliography (with the default `backend=biber,`) the errors you quote usually mean that BibTeX is run instead of Biber. Your document needs to be compiled with Biber, though. If your editor is involved in calling the LaTeX and friends for you that means it is misconfigured. It is weird that this should happen all of a sudden. Double check your settings with https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864.

Comment: The `pdflatex` error `! Undefined control sequence. l.1 \chapter {controller Design}` would most likely come from running `pdflatex` on a chapter file rather than the main tex file, this wouldn't directly break references but could still be responsible if your editor is auto-detecting whether it should run `bibtex` or `biber` based on the file it's compiling (the chapter file presumably contains `\cite`s but no `\usepackage{biblatex}` to indicate `biber` should be used).

Comment: Any news here? As mentioned above this looks like you did not configure your editor to run Biber for you. Unfortunately, we cannot say anything more useful based on the information shared in the question so far. Hence, I intend to vote to close this question in due time if no edit with new information is made.

Comment: I voted to close the question as duplicate of our "configuring the editor for Biber" question, since that is the most likely problem given the information available. If this did not help, I suggest you ask a new question and address the questions we asked in the comments.